# Generating sums of variables with loops in Stata

Tags: loops, variables, stata

I'm having some problems with a loop that I'm trying to perform and probably with the syntax for generating the variable that I want.

Putting in words, what I am trying to do make is a sum of a particular set of observations and storing each sum in a cell for a new variable. Here is an example of syntax that I used:

`forvalues j=1/50 {
replace x1 = sum(houses) if village==`j'`& year==2010
}`

`gen x2=.
forvalues j=1/50 {
replace x2 = sum(houses) if village==`j' `& year==2011
}`

`gen x3 =.
forvalues j=1/50 {
replace x3 = sum(houses) if village==`j' `& year==2012
}`

This is from a dataset with more than 4000 observations. So, for each particular j, if I were successful with the code above, I would get an unique observation for each j (what I want to obtain), but I'm not obtaining this -- which is a sum of all houses, conditioned with the year and village; the total sum of houses per village in each year. I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me obtain one particular observation for each j in each variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sum()` will return a running sum, so that is probably not what you want. This type of problem is usually much easier to solve with the [by:](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?by) prefix in combination with the [egen](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?egen) command. The one line command below will give you the total number of houses per village and year:

```
bys village year: egen Nhouses = total(houses)
```

Comment: Note that `help sum()` takes you directly to a definition.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was trying to search mainly through the internet for the syntax (with no success). But that worked greatly.

Comment: If you want to know something about how to work with Stata, I would not start by looking at the internet but start with the help-files.